# Get index of next smallest element in the list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, compiler-errors

I m a newbie to Haskell. I am pretty good with Imperative languages but not with functional. Haskell is my first as a functional language.

I am trying to figure out, how to get the index of the smallest element in the list where the minimum element is defined by me.

Let me explain by examples.

For example :

Function signature
    minList :: x -> [x]

```
let x = 2
let list = [2,3,5,4,6,5,2,1,7,9,2] 

minList x list --output 1 <- is index
```

This should return 1. Because the at list[1] is 3. It returns 1 because 3 is the smallest element after x (=2).

```
let x = 1
let list = [3,5,4,6,5,2,1,7,9,2] 
minList x list -- output 9 <- is index
```

It should return 9 because at list[9] is 2 and 2 is the smallest element after 1. x = 1 which is defined by me.

What I have tried so far.

```
minListIndex :: (Ord a, Num  a) => a -> [a] -> a
minListIndex x [] = 0
minListIndex x (y:ys) 
            | x > y =  length ys
            | otherwise = m
            where m = minListIndex x ys
```

When I load the file I get this error

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          minListIndex :: forall a. (Ord a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> a
        at myFile.hs:36:17
    • In the expression: 1 + length ys
      In an equation for ‘minListIndex’:
          minListIndex x (y : ys)
            | x > y = 1 + length ys
            | otherwise = 1 + m
            where
                m = minListIndex x ys
    • Relevant bindings include
        m :: a (bound at myFile.hs:41:19)
        ys :: [a] (bound at myFile.hs:38:19)
        y :: a (bound at myFile.hs:38:17)
        x :: a (bound at myFile.hs:38:14)
        minListIndex :: a -> [a] -> a (bound at myFile.hs:37:1)
```

When I modify the function like this

```
minListIndex :: (Ord a, Num  a) => a -> [a] -> a
minListIndex x [] = 0
minListIndex x (y:ys) 
            | x > y =  2 -- <- modified...
            | otherwise = 3 -- <- modifiedd
            where m = minListIndex x ys
```

I load the file again then it compiles and runs but ofc the output is not desired.

What is the problem with

```
| x > y =  length ys
| otherwise = m
```

?

In short: Basically, I want to find the index of the smallest element but higher than the x which is defined by me in parameter/function signature.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind the line `x > y =  length ys`? Why if the first element of the list is smaller than `x` should it return the length of the rest of the list?

Comment: It also is a bit "odd" that you "define the smallest element" yourself. If that is the case, then this basically "collapses" to a [`findIndex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:findIndex).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for answering. I was just testing length ys and It failed. Regarding findIndex, I don't want to import any library. :(

Comment: Based on the examples, it looks like you basically want to find the *index* of the smallest element *after* the given element?

Comment: yes, exactly....

Comment: The code in question may not work the way as you desired, but anyway, if you want it compile, you can use `fromIntegral` function to convert `Int` to `Num` as `fromIntegral $ length ys`.

Comment: re your last edit, no, it contradicts your examples.

Comment: oh yea sorry, I corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
minListIndex :: (Ord a, Num  a) => a -> [a] -> a
```

The problem is that you are trying to return result of generic type `a` but it is actually index in a list.

Suppose you are trying to evaluate your function for a list of doubles. In this case compiler should instantiate function's type to `Double -> [Double] -> Double` which is nonsense.

Actually compiler notices that you are returning something that is derived from list's length and warns you that it is not possible to match generic type `a` with concrete `Int`.

`length ys` returns `Int`, so you can try this instead:

```
minListIndex :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> Int
```

---

Regarding your original problem, seems that you can't solve it with plain recursion. Consider defining helper recursive function with [accumulator](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Accumulating_parameter). In your case it can be a pair `(min_value_so_far, its_index)`.

Comment: This helped me to understand. Is it way to cast the returning value of `length` to Integer or `a`?

Comment: This must not be possible. Otherwise it will allow you to write unsafe code.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'd separate the index type from the list element type altogether. There's no apparent reason for them to be the same. I will use the `BangPatterns` extension to avoid a space leak without too much notation; enable that by adding `{-# language BangPatterns #-}` to the very top of the file. I will also import `Data.Word` to get access to the `Word64` type.

There are two stages: first, find the index of the given element (if it's present) and the rest of the list beyond that point. Then, find the index of the minimum of the tail.

```
-- Find the 0-based index of the first occurrence
-- of the given element in the list, and
-- the rest of the list after that element.
findGiven :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe (Word64, [a])
findGiven given = go 0 where
  go !_k [] = Nothing --not found
  go !k (x:xs)
    | given == xs = Just (k, xs)
    | otherwise = go (k+1) xs

-- Find the minimum (and its index) of the elements of the
-- list greater than the given one.
findMinWithIndexOver :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> Maybe (Word64, a)
findMinWithIndexOver given = go 0 Nothing where
  go !_k acc [] = acc
  go !k acc (x : xs)
    | x <= given = go (k + 1) acc xs
    | otherwise
    = case acc of
        Nothing -> go (k + 1) (Just (k, x)) xs
        Just (ix_min, curr_min)
          | x < ix_min = go (k + 1) (Just (k, x)) xs
          | otherwise = go (k + 1) acc xs
```

You can now put these functions together to construct the one you seek. If you want a general `Num` result rather than a `Word64` one, you can use `fromIntegral` at the very end. Why use `Word64`? Unlike `Int` or `Word`, it's (practically) guaranteed not to overflow in any reasonable amount of time. It's likely substantially faster than using something like `Integer` or `Natural` directly.

Comment: @WillNess, I think I fixed it.

Comment: looks like it. everything is inlined, eliminated, fused; every elem, findIndex, length, span, dropWhile, filter, minimum... and it might as well be written in C. :( :/ :S :L :) .... Wanting a "smart compiler" is frowned  upon, but really, should it be? Still? /ranting/ --- anyway, you've one last optimization to add. it *might* be possible sometimes to bail out early *if* we hit a `successor` minimal element *by pure chance*, with a *discrete* index type (and it *is* discrete). :) (Kind of radix sort--style short-circuiting... Or is it integer sorting?)

Comment: err, it's the element type that must be Enum, not index, d'oh.

Comment: @WillNess, I can fuse the addition in as well if you like, by having `findMinWithIndexOver` take an initial counter value. I could start off with a `zip [0...]`, and maybe I should. The real trouble is the need to deal with the two "not found" cases (i.e., when the given element isn't in the list or when there's nothing greater than it following it). `dropWhile` and `filter` will both want to throw away the length information. Using `length` itself is a waste of time and may also create a space leak. I agree this solution is ugly and C-like, but I don't know how to fix it efficiently.

Comment: /chuckle re:addition/ I understand that it's the price we have to pay more often than we'd liked to. BTW is the code in my answer really that much less efficient? I've implemented the early bail out now, too.

Comment: @WillNess, yours is probably fine. But you need a custom `filterUntil`, which isn't exactly the clearest thing in the world.

Comment: I thought it is now pretty clear, with the Either. It was a mess before, yes. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear for me what do you want exactly. Based on examples I guess it is: *find the index of the smallest element higher than x which appears after x*. In that case, This solution is plain `Prelude`. No imports

```
minList :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> Int
minList x l = snd . minimum . filter (\a -> x < fst a) . dropWhile (\a -> x /= fst a) $ zip l [0..]
```

The logic is:

- create the list of pairs, `[(elem, index)]` using `zip l [0..]`
- drop elements until you find the input `x` using `dropWhile (\a -> x /= fst a)`
- discards elements less than `x` using `filter (\a -> x < fst a)`
- find the minimum of the resulting list. Tuples are ordered using lexicographic order so it fits your problem
- take the index using `snd`

Comment: This solution seems to work for me. But I have small doubt that in which cases a function has to have a signature? Like in your solution, it doesn't have the signature.

Comment: almost always, the compiler can infer the type for you. Nevertheless, it is a bad practice to not specify the signature. I'm editing the answer to add the signature ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be constructed out of ready-made parts as

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)
import Data.List  (sortBy)
import Data.Ord   (comparing)

foo :: (Ord a, Enum b) => a -> [a] -> Maybe b
foo x = fmap fst . listToMaybe . take 1 
                 . dropWhile ((<= x) . snd) 
                 . sortBy (comparing snd) 
                 . dropWhile ((/= x) . snd)
                 . zip [toEnum 0..]
```

This *`Maybe`* *finds* the index of the next smallest element in the list above the given element, situated *after* the given element, in the input list. As you've requested.

You can use any `Enum` type of your choosing as the index.

Now you can implement this higher-level executable specs as direct recursion, using an efficient `Map` data structure to hold your *sorted elements above `x` seen so far* to find the next smallest, etc.

*Correctness first, efficiency later!*

---

Efficiency update: dropping *after* the sort drops them *sorted*, so there's a wasted effort there; indeed it should be replaced with the filtering (as seen in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53758157/849891) by [Luis Morillo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9271266/luis-morillo)) *before* the sort. And if our element type is in `Integral` (so it is a properly discrete type, unlike just an `Enum`, thanks to [@dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477667/dfeuer) for [pointing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53749592/get-index-of-next-smallest-element-in-the-list-in-haskell/53757035?noredirect=1#comment94393490_53757035) this out!), there's one more opportunity for an opportunistic optimization: if we hit on a `succ` minimal element *by pure chance*, there's no further chance of improvement, and so we should bail out at that point right there:

```
bar :: (Integral a, Enum b) => a -> [a] -> Maybe b
bar x = fmap fst . either Just (listToMaybe . take 1 
                                . sortBy (comparing snd))
                 . findOrFilter ((== succ x).snd) ((> x).snd)
                 . dropWhile ((/= x) . snd)
                 . zip [toEnum 0..] 

findOrFilter :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Either a [a]
findOrFilter t p = go 
   where  go []                 = Right []
          go (x:xs) | t x       = Left   x
                    | otherwise = fmap ([x | p x] ++) $ go xs
```

Testing:

```
> foo 5 [2,3,5,4,6,5,2,1,7,9,2] :: Maybe Int
Just 4
> foo 2 [2,3,5,4,6,5,2,1,7,9,2] :: Maybe Int
Just 1
> foo 1 [3,5,4,6,5,2,1,7,9,2] :: Maybe Int
Just 9
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are `Enum` instances for `Float`, `Double`, and `Ratio a`, for which your short-cut approach will fall apart. Yes, that's because `Enum` is extremely broken, but there you go. Perhaps you should use `Integral` instead?

Comment: (on the second thought, I'll just put Integral in as you said. thanks for the suggestion!)